# How to login and get data using python request?

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I am trying to make a script which will login to a url and then get data from it. The webpage is built using jsp, The sample login page looks like this..

```
<html>


    <title>Login</title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    if (self==top) {
      document.documentElement.style.visibility='visible';
    } else {
      top.location=self.location;
    }

    function postSubmit() {
      document.postForm.submit();
    }

        function cookie() {
           var query = "#" + document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
           var docURL = document.URL;
       var now = new Date();
       var time = now.getTime();
       time += 300 * 1000;
       now.setTime(time);

       if (docURL.indexOf("#")>=0){
           document.cookie = "c_read=" + query + "; expires=" + now.toUTCString() + "; domain= .example.com";
       alert(expiryTime.toGMTString());
          }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
        <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/example/auth_submit">
        <div>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password">
        </div>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" onclick="cookie()">
        </form> 

</div>
</body></html>
```

so now i want to login and want to get data from the page after login. So i tried using request as follows;

```
import requests
from lxml import html

USERNAME = "example_user"
PASSWORD = "example_password"

LOGIN_URL = "https://www.loginurl.com"

def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    payload = {
        "userid": USERNAME, 
        "password": PASSWORD,
        "submit":"Login"
    }

    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL)).text
    # tree = html.fromstring(result.content)

    print result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but this code gets only the login page source html, I tried using selenium in which it works fine, but snce i have to put this in a server, I wont be able to use selenium. I am using python 2.7 and request to do it. I dont know what i am doing wrong. Can someone help me out with this

Comment: Your payload key should be username, not userid.

Comment: Also you probably should append /example/auth_submit to your logi n url. The easiest way to do this stuff is usually by opening Chrome Inspector, the network tab, and actually filling out the login form. This lets you see what parameters/payload/headers you need...